Combine the json outputs by removing duplicates
I'm trying to create a form using the json output of the Azure document intelligence . But the output recieved contain three json ,one is the text output and the second is the table data output and third is the key value pairs , i need to combine all three to single json and also have subtract the table data output and key value pairs from the text json so that I can come the json and create form.

Please share the steps or code that you have tried so far as well as any errors.
